# Bjoern v/s Gunicorn POST requests

Tags: python, performance, webserver, gunicorn, bjoern

Isn't Bjoern supposed to faster that Gunicorn ??

simple_app.py

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/suggest/', methods=['POST'])
def hello():
    content = request.get_json()
    return jsonify(**content), 200
```

app_server.py

```
import bjoern
import os
import signal
from simple_app import app

host = '0.0.0.0'
port = 5000
NUM_WORKERS = 2
worker_pids = []


bjoern.listen(app, host, port)
for _ in xrange(NUM_WORKERS):
    pid = os.fork()
    if pid > 0:
        # in master
        worker_pids.append(pid)
    elif pid == 0:
        # in worker
        try:
            bjoern.run()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            pass
        exit()

try:
    for _ in xrange(NUM_WORKERS):
        os.wait()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    for pid in worker_pids:
        os.kill(pid, signal.SIGINT)
```

Running Bjoern server as:

```
python app_server.py
```

Running Gunicorn as:

```
gunicorn -w 2 --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 simple_app:app --timeout 90
```

Main stats:

Gunicorn: request   7.53 msec **highest 10sec mean**

Bjoern: request 1mn 24sec **highest 10sec mean**

Gunicorn::
[image: Gunicorn Request Duration]

[image: Gunicorn Stats]

Bjoern::

[image: Bjoern Request Duration]

[image: Bjoern Stats]

Configuration of the nodes both are ec2 instances: (Used one core to run the app_server, another to run tsung)

Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-115-virtual x86_64)

Number of vCPUs : 2

Comment: Speed is mainly limited by the network. What is your exact setup?

Comment: added the configuration.

Comment: is there something wrong with the way I'm running bjoern ?

Comment: how did you did the benchmark and plotted the graph?

Comment: I used another node to hit the servers using Tsung (we just need a simple xml file to get it running ) http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/1/01/about/

Answer (score 9):

Test bottle + bjoern, it's really fast.
Also bottle + gunicorn + meinheld worker

Bottle is rather faster than flask

bottle: http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/

meinheld: https://github.com/mopemope/meinheld

requests per second:

bottle-py3  408,379

flask-py3   124,800

info: https www techempower.com/benchmarks/#section=data-r13&hw=ph&test=plaintext

Comment: Can you add the link ?

Comment: For future readers, after the claim of bottle better than flask. I went through the rabbit hole. I found that flask is good for projects of any complexity. Bottle is on the other hand better for tiny services. Hope this helps. :)